# Infinite sum related to hypergeometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

I was working on some integrals and I came across the following series: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+n)!}$$ Wolfram Alpha evaluates it to be $$\frac{_2F_2\left(1,1;2,n+2;1\right)}{(n+1)!}$$
Which is a hypergeometric series. I searched on the Internet but I didn't find any useful info and I tried some simple methods to evaluate it but didn't reach anything. I would appreciate any hint, resolution or resource you could give me. I would also appreciate some info about how to evaluate the hypergeometric series shown above.

Comment: I  think the best you can get is an assymptotics

Comment: Another hypergeometric representation for this quantity is 

$$\mathcal S_n=\frac1{n!}\Bigl[{\frac{\partial}{\partial a}}{}_1F_1(a;n+1;1)\Bigr]_{a\to 0} =\frac1{n!}\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{{}_1F_1(a;n+1+a;1)-1}{a}.$$
One can also express the result in terms of exponential integral but this representation contains a special function anyhow. For example,
\begin{align}
\mathcal S_0=& \,\operatorname{Ei}(1)-\gamma,\\
\mathcal S_1=& \,\operatorname{Ei}(1)-\gamma+2-e,\\
\ldots 
\end{align}

Comment: @Startwearingpurple Thanks for your answer! Do you know any resources I can use to learn about this topic, or to know how to derive this?

Comment: It depends very much on what you want, hypergeometric functions is very vast topic. But for the above you only need the definition of the confluent hypergeometric function $_1F_1(a;b;z)$ as a series in $z$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function